# JOIN two tables using full-text search in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have a situation where I am trying to JOIN two tables based on partially matching text data.  I have read the question [Using Full-Text Search in SQL Server 2005 across multiple tables, columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988371/using-full-text-search-in-sql-server-2005-across-multiple-tables-columns) and it appears that my best option is to create a `VIEW` and add a full-text index on the `VIEW`.

Let me start by giving a little background of the situation.  I have an Excel spreadsheet that I need to calculate some pricing for drugs, but the drug names in the spreadsheet do not match exactly to the database where I am pulling the pricing information.  So I figured that using full-text search may be the way to go.

What I have done so far, is exported the spreadsheet as a CSV file and used `BULK INSERT` to import the data into my database.  Now, my drug database has a primary key on `NDC`, but that information is not available on the spreadsheet unfortunately, or my job would be much easier.

I need to basically be able to match `'AMLODIPINE   TAB 5MG'` and `'AMLODIPINE BESYLATE 5MG TAB'`.  This is just one example, but the other drugs are similar.  My issue is that I'm not even sure how I would be able to create a `VIEW` in order to add both columns, without them matching.

Is there a way to use a full-text search in a `JOIN` statement, something like:

```
SELECT i.Description, m.ProdDescAbbr
FROM dbo.ImportTable i
LEFT JOIN dbo.ManufNames m ON m.ProdDescAbbr <something similar to> i.Description
```

**EDIT:**

Not all of the drug names will contain extra words, another example that I am trying to match is: `'ACYCLOVIR    TAB 800MG'` AND `'ACYCLOVIR 800MG TAB'`

Answer (score 2):

in my work I saw this (fancy for me) function `CONTAINSTABLE`, which uses full text index. Maybe to much complicated function for this situation, but I wanted to share.

`Returns a table of zero, one, or more rows for those columns containing precise or fuzzy (less precise) matches to single words and phrases, the proximity of words within a certain distance of one another, or weighted matches`

Overall I see that you will need to prepare search condition (make it text) before looking for it.

Example:

```
SELECT select_list
FROM table AS FT_TBL 
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(table, column, contains_search_condition) AS KEY_TBL
   ON FT_TBL.unique_key_column = KEY_TBL.[KEY];
```

source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx

Comment: I will try this and see if I can apply it to my situation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a

```
CREATE VIEW view_name WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
```

in front of your SQL to create the view.  Then you could

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_name
ON view_name(Description, ProdDescAbbr)
```

Then you can

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON view_name
```

That will let you run a search with

```
WHERE CONTAINS( (Description, ProdDescAbbr), 'search_term')
```

Comment: Basically, I need the `Description` field to BE the search term when querying against `ProdDescAbbr`, if that makes sense.  I am not manually specifying a search term, I need to `JOIN` the two tables based on the `Description` and `ProdDescAbbr` fields being similar.